# what is the best way to learn new Java features since java 1.4.2

Tags: java

I recently started to use Java for work, but I am mostly doing it using my early knowledge about java 1.4. I am aware that there are a great number of new Java features (which I know some, but not thorough enough). 
What is the most effective way to learn those new features, instead of reading those fundamental books with a lot of content I already know.

Comment: Read the parts you *don't* know? Read the 1.5, 1.6, and 1.7 added-features lists/blogs that show up every release?

Comment: In my opinion they've been throwing new features at Java so rapidly that it's impossible to keep up.  The "what's new" stuff will show you the tip of the iceberg, but there's no way to keep up with the steady stream of new APIs.

Comment: @HotLicks - It is not that bad.  You don't need to know all of the APIs.  You only need to the know the ones in the area(s) that you use in your code.

Comment: @Stephen C thats a good point, though Java was pretty stagnant for a while so there were not really a lot of core major changes other than adding Generics. Though there are many smaller more frequent changes.

Comment: The most widely used new features since then are all the language changes introduced in 1.5 (generics, boxing, enhanced for, annotations). As for API additions, `java.util.concurrent` is by far the most important one to know.

Comment: I agree. The point is the way I am doing is based on my knowledge. I could not know what new features could help unless I know it. I sometimes see others' codes and find something interesting. But I can only learn from fragments of code.. A concise summary of those could help I believe. (I will check the "what's new" stuff anyway.)

Comment: @StephenC What I meant 'concise' is completely based on your comments: "You only need to the know the ones in the area(s) that you use in your code". That is what I need to know. Summary does not have to be short, but certainly shorter than the "what's new" documentation and more readable. :)

Comment: @StephenC Ha, it is a bit off the topic. I was only curious if such a thing exists. :) Many people do write articles on blogs for free to share with all people, not really for me. Anyway, I have got useful answers from Marko's answer and somewhere else on internet. Thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 4):

Check what's new in [Java 1.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/features.html), [Java 1.6](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/beta2.html) and [Java 1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/)